# PHP Mysql connection throwing non-object issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This php connection code is throwing an error...

This is the full code:

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "myusername", "mypassword", "mydatabase");

$result = $conn->query("SELECT title FROM mytable");

var_dump($result);

$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '"title":"'. $rs["title"]     . '"}';
}
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
$conn->close();

echo($outp);

?>
```

This is the error that it's throwing:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in **/home/mypath/public_html/connection.php** on line **13**

The error points here:

```
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: why the brace in the quote `}';` ?

Comment: what did `var_dump($result);` show?

Comment: Plus, your query may also have failed; check for errors on your query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php which isn't a ***glorified*** comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query failed. [`mysqli::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns `false` when the query fails, and a `mysql_result` object otherwise.

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Make sure your query is correct by running it on the console. You should also check for an error while running your query.

```
$result = $conn->query("...") or trigger_error($conn->error);
```